# Как сохранить и передать параметры на другую страницу через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет. Пишу по поводу того что:
есть два файла `index` и `index2`, на 1 файле есть 4 блока, при нажатии на который переходим на второй файл `index2`, где расположена кнопка ок. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как после нажатия на кнопку ок во втором файле удалять выбранный ранее блок с определенным id.
Не понимаю как:

1. Передать второму файлу индекс первого блока средством js;
2. Как сохранить эти изменения в первом файле и после возврата на первую страницу сохранить ранее сделанные изменения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

введите сюда описание изображения

```js
function getId(selector) {
  var elemList = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  [].forEach.call(elemList, function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var id = item.id;
      alert(id);
      document.getElementById(id).remove();
    });
  });
}
getId('div');
```

```css
#blok {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.data {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 5vw;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.body-knopka {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <a href="#">
    <div id="blok1">
      <div class="data">
        <h1>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="index2.html">
    <div id="blok2">
      <div class="data">
        <h1>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="index2.html">
    <div id="blok3">
      <div class="data">
        <h1>lccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="index2.html">
      <div id="blok4">
        <div class="data">
          <h1>dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
 <a href="index.html" style="color: red;">Nazad</a>
 <div class="body-knopka">
  <a href="index.html"><input type="submit" name="knopka" value="Ok"></a>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie

Answer (score 3):

Сохранить какие-либо параметры в JavaScript можно несколькими способами:

1. В [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
2. В [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).
3. В [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Например, в случае с `localStorage` это делается так:

```js
// Записываем параметр "element_id" со значением "value"
localStorage.setItem('element_id', 'value');

// На другой странице текущего домена получаем значение этого параметра
var parameter = localStorage.getItem('element_id');

// Чтобы удалить этот параметр достаточно вызвать
localStorage.removeItem('element_id');
```

Comment: еще `IndexedDB`

Comment: и не _на любой другой странице_, а с таким же адресом (доменом)

Comment: @ThisMan, по-моему это подразумевается по умолчанию, также об этом написано на сайте MDN, ссылки на который я привёл в своём ответе. Но этот комментарий я всё же отредактировал .

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Буду пытаться через localStorage